# How do I install AngularJS.Intellisense using GUI instead of console?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, nuget, intellisense

I want to install IntelliSense support for AngularJS. I could do that using the console command [Install-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/) but I'm curious if it's possible to do it using the GUI for packages.

I've tried looking for *angular* which gave a lot of hits. I've also tried *angular.intellisense* which only resulted in one hit - some productivity tools. Is it possible to get that package using the Wizard or do I have to use the console?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try without the dot, just space.

Comment: @kamilk Tried that too. With *js* I get no results. Without it, I only get the productivity tools. See the image in the question. Maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: The screenshot is not the NuGet dialog. You are trying to use the Extensions and Updates dialog which is for installing extensions to Visual Studio not NuGet packages. You should be using the Manage NuGet Packages dialog, which you can get by right clicking the project or solution in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @MattWard Oh, stupid donkey... Too tired to think straight. Thanks! Now that we're on the subject - should I add *AngularJS.Core* and *AngularJS* too? It seemed to work without those but maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: AngularJS.Intellisense installs AngularJS.Core which has angular.js. The AngularJS NuGet does not depend on AngularJS.Core and includes its own angular.js file as well as several other .js files. All three NuGet packages were created by different people. If installing AngularJS.Intellisense works then there is no reason to install angularjs.

Comment: @MattWard You might want to put that as a reply so I can green-check it. And you might also want to check [the follow-up questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725978/vs-nuget-manager-confused-with-different-versions-of-angular-and-intellisense) I have based on that. The thing that confuses me the most is that I expected the main (central, global, default, core'ish - call it whatever) set of files of AngularJS to be required in any case. But you make it sound like if I'm not necessarily have to install AngularJS into my project at all. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Looking at the NuGet packages you can use either angularjs or AngularJS.Core but not both since they both have an angular.js file. For intellisense you cannot install AngularJS.Intellisense if you want the latest AngularJS.Core NuGet package, currently 1.4.7, so instead you can probably just download the NuGet package, extract the files and add the files directly to your project instead of using installing NuGet package. I assume the intellisense NuGet package does not support intellisense for the latest angular 1.4.7.

Comment: @MattWard Great info, thanks. It might be me who's been spoiled by the modus operandi of MS - coming from C#, I always expect full support for intellisense, debugging and what not. The fewer decisions I need to make, the less distractions in my work. Perhaps it's easier to implement for hard typed, compilable languages than the elasticly flexible script languages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot is not the NuGet dialog. You are trying to use the Extensions and Updates dialog which is for installing extensions to Visual Studio not NuGet packages. You should be using the Manage NuGet Packages dialog, which you can get by right clicking the project or solution in the Solution Explorer.